# Streaming replication postgresql cluster

Tags: postgresql

I am setting up a postgresql cluster through pgpool-II. Right now the pgpool part *seems* to be ok, in the sense that it does not report any error and all the commands return successfully after setting up the first follower. This is what I am running:

1. on the primary: SELECT pg_create_physical_replication_slot('pg_1');
2. on a completely empty database, through a connection from pgpool:

- rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/data/* /var/lib/postgresql/archivedir/*
- pg_basebackup -h pg-0 -U replicator -p 5432 -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -X stream
- create /var/lib/postgresql/data/myrecovery.conf with this contents:

```
    primary_conninfo = 'host=pg-0 port=5432 user=replicator application_name=pg-1 passfile=''/var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass'''
    recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
    restore_command = 'scp pg-0:/var/lib/postgresql/archivedir/%f %p'
    primary_slot_name = 'pg_1'
```

(note: this file is already include_if_exists on the postgresql config file)

- the file /var/lib/postgresql/data/standby.signal gets touched.

3. on the just created database, through a connection from pgpool:

- pg_ctl -l /dev/null -w -D /var/lib/postgresql/data status || pg_ctl -l /dev/null -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -o '--config-file=/etc/postgresl/postgresql.conf' start

Now: I can see that the server on pg-1 is just waiting for the connection to succeed. On the other hand, on pg-0 I get the following output, repeated every few seconds:

```
 [1] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
 [1] DEBUG:  server process (PID 3196) exited with exit code 255
 [1] LOG:  server process (PID 3196) exited with exit code 255
 [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
 [1] DEBUG:  sending SIGQUIT to process 3194
 [1] DEBUG:  sending SIGQUIT to process 3190
 [1] DEBUG:  sending SIGQUIT to process 3189
 [1] DEBUG:  sending SIGQUIT to process 3191
 [1] DEBUG:  sending SIGQUIT to process 3192
 [1] DEBUG:  sending SIGQUIT to process 3193
 [1] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
 [3193] DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat/global.stat"
 [1] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
 [3193] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3193] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3193] DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
 [1] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
 [1] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
 [1] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [1] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 5 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [1] DEBUG:  cleaning up dynamic shared memory control segment with ID 899647808
 [1] DEBUG:  invoking IpcMemoryCreate(size=15769600)
 [1] DEBUG:  mmap(16777216) with MAP_HUGETLB failed, huge pages disabled: Out of memory
 [1] DEBUG:  dynamic shared memory system will support 674 segments
 [1] DEBUG:  created dynamic shared memory control segment 1156494630 (26976 bytes)
 [1] DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=3198 socket=9
 [3197] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2022-06-08 16:50:23 GMT
 [3197] DEBUG:  removing all temporary WAL segments
 [3198] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
 [3198] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3198] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3198] DEBUG:  proc_exit(1): 1 callbacks to make
 [3198] DEBUG:  exit(1)
 [3198] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3198] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3198] DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
 [1] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
 [1] DEBUG:  server process (PID 3198) exited with exit code 1
 [1] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
 [1] DEBUG:  server process (PID 3200) exited with exit code 255
 [3197] DEBUG:  checkpoint record is at 0/3005530
 [3197] DEBUG:  redo record is at 0/3005530; shutdown true
 [3197] DEBUG:  next transaction ID: 736; next OID: 24576
 [3197] DEBUG:  next MultiXactId: 1; next MultiXactOffset: 0
 [3197] DEBUG:  oldest unfrozen transaction ID: 727, in database 1
 [3197] DEBUG:  oldest MultiXactId: 1, in database 1
 [3197] DEBUG:  commit timestamp Xid oldest/newest: 0/0
 [3197] DEBUG:  transaction ID wrap limit is 2147484374, limited by database with OID 1
 [3197] DEBUG:  MultiXactId wrap limit is 2147483648, limited by database with OID 1
 [3197] DEBUG:  starting up replication slots
 [3197] DEBUG:  restoring replication slot from "pg_replslot/pg_1/state"
 [3197] DEBUG:  starting up replication origin progress state
 [3197] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
 [3197] DEBUG:  resetting unlogged relations: cleanup 1 init 0
 [3197] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/30055A8: wanted 24, got 0
 [3197] LOG:  redo is not required
 [3197] DEBUG:  resetting unlogged relations: cleanup 0 init 1
 [3197] DEBUG:  performing replication slot checkpoint
 [3197] DEBUG:  attempting to remove WAL segments older than log file 000000000000000000000002
 [3197] DEBUG:  MultiXactId wrap limit is 2147483648, limited by database with OID 1
 [3197] DEBUG:  MultiXact member stop limit is now 4294914944 based on MultiXact 1
 [3197] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3197] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 7 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3197] DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
 [3197] DEBUG:  exit(0)
 [3197] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3197] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
 [3197] DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
 [1] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
 [3201] DEBUG:  checkpointer updated shared memory configuration values
 [3204] DEBUG:  autovacuum launcher started
 [1] DEBUG:  starting background worker process "logical replication launcher"
 [3204] DEBUG:  InitPostgres
 [3204] DEBUG:  my backend ID is 1
 [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 [3204] DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3207] DEBUG:  logical replication launcher started
 [3204] DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3207] DEBUG:  InitPostgres
 [3207] DEBUG:  my backend ID is 2
 [3206] DEBUG:  received inquiry for database 0
 [3206] DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
 [3207] DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3207] DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3207] DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3207] DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3207] DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3207] DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3204] DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3204] DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [1] DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=3208 socket=9
 [3208] DEBUG:  InitPostgres
 [3208] DEBUG:  my backend ID is 3
 [3208] DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3208] DEBUG:  processing received SASL response of length 50
 [3208] DEBUG:  sending SASL challenge of length 84
 [3208] DEBUG:  processing received SASL response of length 104
 [3208] DEBUG:  sending SASL challenge of length 46
 [3208] DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
 [3208] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
```

I am completely lost: what is going on?

Comment: connect the slot directly to pg, don't try to make a replica connection via pg-pool. ITOH, skip step 1, let basebasckup do the work, and 3 just start.

pg_basebackup -D /data/dir --wal-method=stream --verbose --progress -P -hx.x.x.x -Upostgres -p5432 --write-recovery-conf --checkpoint=fast --create-slot --slot=slotname >>/tmp/basebackup  2>>/tmp/basebackup &

Comment: @FrankNStein Thank you very much! by using your suggestion I have reduced quite a bit my script, and while doing so I have discovered I was using a wrong setting in my postgresql configuration. Now, at least, from the point of view of postgresql all works. Now I need to get pgpool to detect the standby servers as stream and async... still work to do!